# text-align:center has no effect

Tags: html, css

I am using some CSS with classes to style different types of text. I am styling some links with a class called `a.searchresult`. One of the attributes is `text-align:center`, but it is having no effect on the text - it stays aligned to the left. Why is this happening?

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
a.searchresult
{
font-family:Trebuchet MS;
font-size:20px;
text-align:center;
color:blue;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class = "content">
<h2 class = "main">Search results for post deletion in topics</h2>
<br /><br />
<!--This link is aligned left-->
<a class = 'searchresult' href = 'display_post.php?id=15'>Post deletion</a><p class = 'searchresult'>At last, I did it!</p><br /><br />
</div>
```

Bear in mind that the link is being echoed from PHP. I don't know if that would affect it, but I thought I should mention it.

Comment: `a` isn't a block element so put `display:block` to it to gain the parents width. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/efsrt/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put it in a container and set `text-align: center;` to the container OR make it a block element, `display: block;`. `a` tags are inline elements so `text-align` won't work on them.

Here's an example of it working as a block element: http://jsfiddle.net/a9YAp/

And here in a div: http://jsfiddle.net/pmsSV/

Comment: Firstly, why? Secondly, it is already in a div. Also, my h2 class has text-align:center and that works

Comment: I tried putting it in a span with text-align:center but it didn't work

Comment: <span> is also an inline element. Just look at the first jsfiddle and set the 'a' tag to have display: block; http://jsfiddle.net/a9YAp/

Comment: works with display:block; Thanks! Will accept when it lets me

Answer (score 1):

Your width will have no effect as you can not set the width of an `a` tag without changing it's display properities. this is why `text-align` does not appear to be working

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/CJdvQ/1/

```
a.searchresult
{
font-family:Trebuchet MS;
font-size:20px;
text-align:center;
color:blue;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:500px;
border: thin solid black;

}
```

add `display:block;` and it will work fine.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/CJdvQ/2/

Comment: well, your fiddle shows left-aligned text with a border. That's not what I want...

Comment: The first DEMO is showing text-align not working due to it;s display properties. The border is there to show you where the `a` tag is starting and finishing to show you that it does not let you set a width.

Comment: oh, sorry, missed the second one :) +1 anyway

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.content{
width:500px;
text-align:center;
}

a.searchresult
{
font-family:Trebuchet MS;
font-size:20px;
color:blue;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

Comment: no, that has no effect. Why are you answering this when nick got it 1 hour ago?

Answer (score 0):

DEMO here... http://jsfiddle.net/94Ty9/

add this css...

## CSS

```
a.searchresult
{
    font-family:Trebuchet MS;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    color:blue;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your `<a>`  tag into a div!then `text-align:center`

```
<div class = "content">
    <h2 class = "main">Search results for post deletion in topics</h2>
    <br /><br />
    <!--This link is aligned left-->
    <div id="Holder">
    <a class = 'searchresult' href = 'display_post.php?id=15'>Post deletion</a><p class = 'searchresult'>At last, I did it!</p><br /><br />
    </div>
    </div>






 a.searchresult
{
font-family:Trebuchet MS;
font-size:20px;
text-align:center;
color:blue;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#Holder
{
    text-align:center;
    }
```

Comment: That is an exact copy of @nick's answer without the suggestion of display:block

Comment: @imulsion:OK,but i never copy his answer for you because this answer is also clearly for all web designers and this is not important for me!I tried to help you JUST.

Answer (score -1):

You should try giving the element or the element above a width

```
a.searchresult
{
font-family:Trebuchet MS;
font-size:20px;
text-align:center;
color:blue;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:300px;
}
```